# How does the probability change when changing the decission?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let's say you play roulette and you set 2 coins of 2 of the 3 columns or dozens. Then your chance is 2/3rd, so about 66% to win one coin. Let's assume that you loose because the other dozen or column comes, does the chance rises when you choose your mind and set the column or dozen you didn't set before? I don't think so because every round has it's own probability and the probabilities of each round does not affect the upcoming rounds, but if it's so easy, why is statistics and probability calculation such a big topic. So is there any reason that the chance is getting higher to change your mind?
And if there is really any reason, does the chance rise more when you switch back for that case, that you set the wrong column or dozen the second time? I don't think so.

[image: Roulette]

Comment: If the rounds are truly independent, then it doesn't matter.  In a sense though, all of these games are pseudorandom.  I mean, if you could somehow analyze the physical state from game to game, it might be the case that from round-to-round you could show it's not quite independent or it might even be the case that you could predict the outcome.  That all seems highly unlikely to me because the game (roulette at least) is probably such that it represents a physically chaotic system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit oddly worded but to answer what you seem to have answered well enough yourself: No, changing your mind will not have any affect.

If the number 1 was rolled 4 times in a row and you had selected the second two columns for your bet then only because it could not hurt you to switch to include the first column would I advise switching. If there is no reason to believe that the table is rigged or biased then even if it rolled 1 50 times in a row there would be no real reason to switch. The moral is once the probability reaches the absurd should one consider there may be some reason to switch where normally it would make no difference.

Comment: If you saw a 1 rolled 50 times in a row, then you would have extremely strong statistical evidence that the game was not fair (even 4 times in a row, probably gives over a 50% chance that the game isn't fair).